# Why is sleeping with shoes on a taste of death?

Tags: clothing, death, sleep, masechet-yoma

The gemarah in [Yoma 78b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=78b&format=text) teaches that sleeping with shoes is a taste of death. This is also codified [in halacha](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=2187). I would like to understand why this is the case. What is it about sleeping with shoes that relates to death?

Comment: Weird. I thought sleeping is a taste (or a sixtieth actually) of death irrespective of one's footwear.

Comment: @msh210 האי מאן דבעי למיטעם טעמא דמיתותא ליסיים מסאני וליגני

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I didn't say I disbelieved the question's citation of _Yoma_. I only said that _Yoma_ is curious, as IIRC there's another _midrash_ that says sleep, even barefoot, is a sixtieth of death.

Comment: @msh210 Yoma is indded curious. Here is the quote from [Berochos 57b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=57b&format=text): שינה אחד מששים למיתה

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is discussed in [hatorah.net](http://www.hatora.net/2011/01/26/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA-%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7-%D7%91-%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%99/)

There under קיב ע"א, he notes that Talmidei Chachomim only took their shoes off on Friday night. He records Yoma 78b and says *(my translation of an extract)*

> it can be explained through Rav Nachman bar Yitzchok's maamar in
>   Gittin 57b on the possuk      (כי עליך הורגנו כל היום"  (תהלים מד"  
>   which he says refers to Talmidei Chachomim who (figuratively) kill
>   themselves for Divrei Torah. This is like Reb Shimon ben Lokish who
>   says that  divrei Torah do not last except for someone who kills
>   himself for them expounding on the possuk “This is the Torah. When a
>   man dies in the tent etc.” [Bamidbor 19:14](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9947#). Through their great devotion
>   to Torah they learn it day and night and only when sleep catches them
>   do they take a short sleep without even taking off their shoes like
>   our father Yaakov who is 14 years in the Beis Hamedrash of Shem and
>   Ever did not lie down to sleep.

So it seems that  Talmidei Chachomim fulfill the drosho on the possuk “This is the Torah. When a man dies in the tent etc.” by never deliberately resting from their studies and hence never taking their shoes off to sleep. This is the connection between  sleeping with shoes and death.

Full quote in Hebrew:

> קיב ע"א      פטור אבל אסור בדרבנן. וכתב הריטב"א "ר"י ז"ל פירש כי אף
>   מנעל דרבנן מהודק הוא יפה אלא שאין דרכן לחלוץ מנעליהם אלא מלילי שבת
>   [ללילי שבת] מפני שכל השבוע ישנים במנעליהם לפי שעוסקים בתורה כל
>   הלילה".    וביומא עח ע"ב "אמר שמואל האי מאן דבעי למיטעם טעמא דמיתותא,
>   ליסיים מסאני וליגני" ויתכן שבזה יבואר כפשוטו מאמר רב נחמן בר יצחק
>   (גיטין נז ע"ב) "כי עליך הורגנו כל היום" (תהלים מד) – אלו ת"ח שממיתין
>   עצמן על דברי תורה כדר' שמעון בן לקיש דאמר ר' שמעון בן לקיש אין דברי
>   תורה מתקיימין אלא במי שממית עצמו עליהם שנאמר "זאת התורה אדם כי ימות
>   באהל וגו'" (במדבר יט)". וברוב התמדתם היו עוסקים תדיר בתורה יום ולילה
>   ורק שחוטפתן שינה היו נמים מעט ללא שהות אפי' לחלוץ מנעליהם, כאבינו יעקב
>   שכל י"ד שנה שהיה בבית מדרשם של שם ועבר לא שכב לישון. וודאי שנרדם בעל
>   כרחו (ראה נדרים טו) אלא שהיה לומד עד שחטפתו שינה. וכמו שרב ששת בברכות
>   כה ע"א אומר "אתו חזו הני ציפי דבי רב דהני גנו והני גרסי" ומסביר רש"י,
>   שעל מחצלאות בית המדרש היו חלק נמים וחלק לומדים, ומכך שהתירו להמשיך
>   בגירסת הלימוד אפי' שדרך הישנים להפיח, משום שאי אפשר אחרת (רש"י שם),
>   משמע שלא היתה זו שינה מסודרת אלא היו לומדים עד שאחזתם שינה וממלא נרדמו
>   וחזרו והתעוררו ולמדו, ולכן היו חלק כך וחלק כך. ולשינה מסודרת היה
>   אושפיזא (שבת קמ ע"ב וברש"י שם ד"ה לאושפיזא). ונמצא שהיו ישנים עם
>   נעליהם כדברי ר"י, וטעמו טעם מיתה ולכן אמר רב נחמן בר יצחק שהפסוק "עליך
>   הורגנו כל היום" נאמר על אותם ת"ח שממיתים עצמם באהלה של תורה, דהיינו
>   מחמת שלא יוצאים מרוב התמדתם מאהלה של תורה, טועמים טעם מיתה ע"י שינה
>   בנעליהם.

Comment: +1 Great pshat. And here I was wondering how to reconcile the two mamarim and really they are working hand in hand.